# What is the difference between 姿勢 vs 態勢 vs 体勢？

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 姿勢 vs 態勢 vs 体勢？ They all seem to mean "posture" or "attitude."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 態勢

Preparedness for response that is temporary or limited. (For standardized, sustained, or permanent systems and functions, use 体制 instead.)

- 着陸態勢に入る *prepare for landing*
- 移民の受け入れ態勢を整える *prepare for accepting immigrants*

### 体勢

Bodily posture, position, or form.

- 有利な体勢 *advantageous position*
- 射撃体勢 *shooting position*

### 姿勢

Bodily posture or position; attitude.

- 姿勢がいい *have good posture*
- 謙虚な姿勢 *humble attitude*

When referring to bodily postures, I seem to use 姿勢 when mainly the spine is involved, and 体勢 when limbs are involved. They're pretty interchangeable though.

---

Reference: [「体制」「態勢」「体勢」などの使い分け](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/173.html)